# CakePHP: Accessing session data from within a controller

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have an edit action in the users controller. What I want to do is redirect anyone to a different action if their Auth.User.id does not equal the id of the user they are trying to edit.

I can access variables in my views like this:

```
if($session->read('Auth.User.id') != $id){
```

but this doesn't work in my controller. Getting:

```
Undefined variable: session
```

How do I access session data within a controller? also, if any has a better way of achieving what I want to do, feel free to add!

Thanks,

Jonesy

Comment: Just a friendly reminder to try and do as much logic as possible in the controller. The more you keep to CakePHP's coding conventions the more you'll thank yourself later. ;) Feel free to take a look at them in-depth at http://book.cakephp.org/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions Happy baking!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must first add Session as a component in your controller:

`var $components= array('Session');`

You can then access it in your methods via `$this->Session`

Comment: +1 for general correctness, but he should add Session as a component, not a helper.  (though usually both.)

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I mixed up components and helpers. I've edited.

Answer (score 4):

You can read Session data in a controller with `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');` The CakePHP Session component, if I remember correctly, is automatically loaded into all controllers unless you have defined the default components elsewhere. If `$this->Session` is undefined, include it into your `$components` array in your controller like `var $components = array('Session');`

It's important to note that Helpers are not the same as Components. Generally speaking, Components are extended functionality for your Controller. Whereas Helpers are extended functionality for your view.

For a complete look at all possible methods, the CakePHP Cookbook will be invaluable for you! http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions